# Box Topology and Discrete Spaces.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Is box topology in infinite spaces equal to discrete  topology always.

Answer (score 3):

The only time the box topology on $\displaystyle S = \prod_{i \in I} S_i$ is discrete is when each $S_i$ is discrete.  This is revealed by the fact that a given $U \subset S$ is open $\iff \pi_k(U)$ is open for every projection map $\pi_k: S \rightarrow S_k$.